# Comparison Algorithm of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I have one list and want to compare the all the values from the list and store in empty list. I have below list:

```
store_list = [0,1,4,5,10,6,7,8]
final_list = [] 
If value of particular index is greater than all the previous indices values and less than all 
the occurring values then that value should store in the empty list.
```

Maybe this is very simple question but I am not able to build the above logic.

Required output will be:

```
final_list = [0, 1, 5]
//0 is less than all the occurring values, so it is in the list
//5 is greater than previous values and less than all the other occurring 
  values so it is in lists
```

Comment: What is the required output, and please show your work so far.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Are you asking this: If the value of a particular index, let's take value 5 in the 4th element, is greater than all the previous indices values, so 5 is greater than all the previous indices (0 through 3 indices) which have values (0,1,4) and less than the occurring values (after...?) so less than 2,3,4,1, then store that value? By that logic, I don't think any of them in this list would be stored.

Comment: @jammin0921 : I have shown required output and explained why it is in the list. Just take a look

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
store_list = [0,1,4,5,10,6,7,8]
final = []
for i,item in enumerate(store_list):
    if item > max(store_list[:i], default=float('-inf')) and item < min(store_list[i+1:], default=float('inf')):
        final += [item]

final
```

[0, 1, 4, 5]
`This should be your output`

You can also use list comprehension as follows to replace the loop

```py
final = [item for i,item in enumerate(store_list) if item > max(store_list[:i], default=float('-inf')) and item < min(store_list[i+1:], default=float('inf'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, is this the logic you're looking for? I'm confused if you want the condition for the index or the value. If you want to compare a value with an index then you can try the code below.

```
for index,item in enumerate(store_list):
    if (store_list[index] > index-1) and (store_list[index] < index+1):
        final_list.append(store_list[index])
```

Maybe you can give a desired output. It would be easy to understand.

Comment: I want the condition for the values. I want to compare the values within lists. Means, first value in the list is '0', so 0 will get compared and if 0 is greater than previous values in the list and 0 is less than the occurring values in the list then 0 should append in empty list. The second value is '1', so if 1 is greater than previous values in the list and less than the occurring values in the list than 1 will be in appended otherwise not. This should continue for all the values.

Comment: What do you mean by occuring values, do you mean all elements after that particular element.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian: Occurring values means next all the values in the lists.

Comment: Alright, then why haven't you included `1` in your output. It is greater than `0` and smaller than all elements after it.

Comment: @SurajSubramanian: Yes, 1 will also come. Sorry for that. Really sorry, I will edit it.

Comment: Similarly `4` will also come, you can refer my answer below.